# I could not find the problem with my code

Tags: c, pointers, struct

This is my class assignment and my first time writing in c. I am trying to read files, store them in a buffer then XOR the read bytes finally store the output to another file. Everything seems correct, but I got a segmentation error. I could not figure out what I have missed.
I have tried to find if the functions I used caused this but nothing. I have also searched stackoverflow. I would really appreciate a help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


const int BUFFER_SIZE = 10000;
const long FILE_SIZE = 100000000;

typedef struct file_buffer_struct 
  {
    char * buffer;
    FILE * pFile;
  } file_buffer;



int main (int argc, char *argv[] ) {
 printf("hello | ");

  FILE *outputF ;
  int i;
  int j;
  int k;
  int result;

  file_buffer FB[10];
  outputF = fopen ( argv[argc] , "wb");



  if ( (argc < 4) && (argc > 13) ) // argc should be greater than 4 or less than or equal to 12 for correct execution 
    {
        printf( "please give arguments greater than 3 and less than 11 !");
        return 0;
    }


  //xor_all_buffers(&FB, &outputF);

  for(i=1; i<argc; i++)
  {
    FB[i].pFile = fopen( argv[i] , "rb" );
    FB[i].buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*BUFFER_SIZE);
  }


  char * xored_buffer = (char *) malloc(BUFFER_SIZE); 


  for (int index=0; index < FILE_SIZE ;) {
      memset(xored_buffer, 0, sizeof(xored_buffer));

      for (int i=0; i < sizeof(FB); i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < BUFFER_SIZE; j++, index++) { 
          xored_buffer[j] = xored_buffer[j] ^ FB[i].buffer[index]; 
        }

      }
      result=fwrite(xored_buffer, sizeof(char), BUFFER_SIZE, outputF); 
  }


  printf("hello | ");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is file opened? Is buffer allocation successful?

Comment: Use a debugger. Check every value returned from every function.

Comment: Segmentation faults can show up for many reasons if you're lucky (if you're unlucky the code will work consistently enough for you not to notice the errors). The easiest way to find the cause in the future is through the use of a debugger, which will give you a lot more to work with than the cryptic error messages.

Comment: "*`if ( (argc < 4) && (argc > 13) )`*": How could `argc` ever be less then four **and** greater then eleven at  the same tme?

Comment: @alk , thanks for pointing that out

Comment: The posted code does not cleanly compile!.   When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to obtain the same information.

Comment: regarding: `outputF = fopen ( argv[argc] , "wb");`   in C, the valid range for an index into an array is 0...(number of elements in array -1)   ARGV[] contains a final (uncounted) argument containing NULL.  So this statement is accessing the NULL entry in the array of arguments.   Also, never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the expected command line parameters were actually entered

Comment: regarding: `file_buffer FB[10];`  Where is the definition of variable type `file_buffer`?   Perhaps you meant: `FILE *`

Comment: OT: regarding: `FB[i].buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*BUFFER_SIZE);`   1) in C, the returned type from the heap allocation functions is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Suggest removing the cast;  2) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has absolutely not effect, clutters the code, etc.  Suggest removing that expression.  3) where is `BUFFER_SIZE` defined?

Comment: regarding: `for (int i=0; i < sizeof(FB); i++) {`   1) The `sizeof(FB)` returns the total number of bytes in the array `FB`  Probably not what you want.  2) the `sizeof()` returns a `size_t`, not a `int`, Your compiler should have told you about this.  3) the number of entries in the array `FB` is what should have been used as the limit for the loop count `i`

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  Like: 10.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or a `#define` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: OT: regarding: `if ( (argc < 4) && (argc > 13) ) // argc should be greater than 4 or less than or equal to 12 for correct execution 
    {
        printf( "please give arguments greater than 3 and less than 11 !");
        return 0;
    }`  1) returning 0 indicates success.  Suggest returning `EXIT_FAILURE` (as defined in the header file: `stdlib.h`)  2)  When the wrong number of parameters are entered on the command line,  Then should output to `stderr` a USAGE message, similar to `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <description of all parameters>\n", argv[0] );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
outputF = fopen ( argv[argc] , "wb");
```

Argc stands for arg count which is the number of elements in the argv (argument vector) array. However indexes in C are zero based. So if an array has a length of n elements the index of the last element is n - 1 and the first element is 0.

EDIT: [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142924/weather-vane)  so helpfully pointed out the last element in argv is actually a NULL (zero) value. Interpreted as a char * which is probably your segfault right there. Use gdb and printf to help you debug and find out when your program crashes [nice intro to gdb](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gdb-step-by-step-introduction/)

The if condition

```
if ( (argc < 4) && (argc > 13) )
```

Generally speaking should be checked before you attempt to use argc. Think what if no arguments were given? Why have the check after usage. Also you might want to rethink this condition. When will it be less than 4 *and* greater than 13. Perhaps you intended on using an OR?

```
for(i=1; i<argc; i++)
```

Again same problem indexes are zero based.

```
xored_buffer[j] ^ FB[i].buffer[index]
```

Where did you actually set the value of FB[i].buffer[index]

You might also want to check how the sizeof operator actually works

[reading](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sizeof-operator-c/) and a [simple example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08539eba2f797c0e) Keep in mind that an array with a compile time known size is different than a pointer that may point to one or more elements.

Comment: @Babydesta `argv[argc]` is `NULL`, a sentinel value at the end of the array (in this case) after the arguments.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that `argc` is never going to be less than 4 and greater than 13. Presumably should be `||` not `&&`.

Comment: Everyone thanks, my code still didnot work but I know I'm making progress. so Thanks a lot.

Comment: "*`(argc < 4) && (argc > 13)`*" is never true.